# Reading columns from csv to R with GLM

Tags: r, excel, csv, glm

I'm trying to use a generalized linear model to analyze ecological food consumption data between 2 different species (N and NN):

```
dat1.glm<-glm(Contact~Density + Species, data=dat1, family=binomial)
```

I have attached an image which shows how the .csv file is formatted. After summary(dat1.glm), the result I get is

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value      Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.1873     0.7494  -0.250   0.8026  
Density       0.2126     0.1049   2.027   0.0427 *
SpeciesNN    -0.2911     0.7650  -0.381   0.7035
```

For some reason the variable "Species" shows up as "SpeciesNN" and I'm afraid this is skewing the results of the analysis. Any idea on how to fix this?

[format of .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPHrR.png)

Comment: It appears that species is bring imported at a factor with two levels ("N" and "NN"). By default factors will use reference level coding and R has used "N" as the reference level so you just get an intercept for NN. Not sure what your specific fear is.

Comment: Thanks. Haha, probably the wrong choice of words. Just started using R and thought I made some error.

Comment: Well, R is just basically a fancy calculator. It assumes that you know and understand the statistical models you are using. So it's good to make sure you know exactly what's going on in order to correctly interpret results.

Comment: A lot of these sorts of basic questions are general (i.e. apply to linear as well as generalized linear models); I'd recommend sitting down with one of the many introductions to modeling in R (e.g. google "linear models R") and getting a bit more background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not need to be fixed. The two species in your data set are `N` and `NN`; by default, R orders them alphabetically (`N` before `NN`), and labels the species effects according to the species.  So `SpeciesNN` means "the difference between the baseline species (`N`) and species `NN`".

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates comments that say "thank you"; you can click on the check-mark to accept the answer.